# Why was the addition of trailing-return-types necessary in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, trailing-return-type

I've finally started to read up on [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and I fail to understand why trailing-return-types are required.

I came across the following example, which is used to highlight the problem:

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  decltype(lhs+rhs) adding_func(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs) {return lhs + rhs;}
```

The example is illegal, because `decltype(lhs+rhs)` does not work, since the identifiers `lhs` and `rhs` are only valid after the parsing phase.

**I guess my question is about the timing of `decltype` type resolution**. If I am not mistaken, the keyword `decltype` is used to determine the type of an expression at compile-time.

I fail to see a downside to having `decltype` perform type resolution after all parsing is completed (which would work fine for the above example). I believe this would have been a simpler way to solve the problem...

Instead, the C++11 standard provides trailing-return-types:

```
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  auto adding_func(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs) -> decltype(lhs+rhs) {return lhs + rhs;}
```

I have no doubt that I am missing something, since I fail to see the other use of trailing-return-types. Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

The trailing-return-types seem like an overly complex solution to me since having `decltype` type resolution after parsing the full function body would work just as well?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I fail to see a downside to having decltype perform type resolution after all parsing is completed (which would work fine for the above example).

The downside is that it's not possible without fundamentally altering the basic foundations of the C++ parsing and processing model.

In order to do what you suggest, the compiler will have to see the `decltype` syntax and do some basic lexical analysis of the contents of the syntax. Then, it goes on to parse more of the source file. At some later point (when?), it decides to go, "hey, that stuff I looked at before? I'm going to do all of the parsing work for them now."

As a general rule, C++ doesn't support looking *ahead* for the definition of symbols. The basic assumption of the C++ parsing framework is that, if the symbol is not declared before it is used, it is a compiler error.

Classes can get away with lookahead, but only with respect to their members. This is in part because its quite clear when an id-expression could be referring to a member variable (ie: if it's not referring to an already declared local or global variable in scope). That's not the case here, where we're not sure what exactly the id-expression could be referring to.

Furthermore, what you suggest creates ambiguities. What does this mean:

```
int lhs;

template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  decltype(lhs+rhs) adding_func(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs);
```

Is the decltype syntax refering to the global `lhs` variable, or the local `lhs` function parameter?

The way we do it now, there's a clear delineation between these two:

```
int lhs;
float rhs;

template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  decltype(lhs+rhs) adding_func1(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs);
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  auto adding_func2(const Lhs &lhs, const Rhs &rhs) -> decltype(lhs+rhs);
```

`adding_func1` refers to the global variables. `adding_func2` refers to the function parameter.

So you can either radically break every C++ compiler on the face of the Earth. Or you can simply late-specify your return type.

Or you can take the C++14 approach and [not bother to state it at all](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html).

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer, I see the uses now. I wish I could give an extra cookie for the C++14 reference!

Comment: On the C++14 thing: is it final that that is going to be included? It sounds like a world of hurt in terms of documentation…

Comment: @MFH: It's in the [C++14 Community Draft](http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/new-paper-n3690-programming-languages-c-committee-draft). So baring unforeseen consequences, it's probably going to be in C++14. And yes, it could be somewhat painful for documentation. But then again, it means you don't have pointless redundency like using `decltype` to deduce the type which corresponds exactly to the code *in the function*.

Comment: @NicolBolas: For functions with "`decltype` return types" this may not be that bad, as those (at least from what I've encountered) are templates and therefore already fully available. On the other hand for normal functions this seems like a can of worms.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am slightly surprised that `decltype` will become somewhat obsolete in the next version of the standard, right after being introduced. That seems to be what will happen.

Comment: @MarcClaesen: `decltype` is useful for more than just late-specified return types.

Answer (score 4):

Well one obvious problem is that it would open you up to loops.

```
typedef decltype(lhs+lhs) foo;
foo lhs;
```

Comment: Yes, I see how that would be problematic. But those kinds of things seem like clear programming errors to me and could be solved by compile-time errors.

Comment: @MarcClaesen: But it's not a "clear" error. In order to detect this type of error, the compiler would have to solve the Halting Problem, which is impossible.

Comment: Oh my, can't believe I missed that. Thanks @MikeSeymour!