# Reason for decltype in trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, trailing-return-type

I was reading a text about the "new" C++ features and came across **decltype** and usage of that. I understand the reasoning behind the **decltype** in the trailing return type of something like

```
template <typename lhsT, typename rhsT>
auto add(lhsT& lhs, rhsT& rhs) -> decltype(lhs + rhs) {
    return lhs +rhs;
}
```

Without it, the compiler would not be able to derive the return type of the template function. But why is the syntax the way it is?

Why not use something like

```
template <typename lhsT, typename rhsT>
decltype(lhs + rhs) add(lhsT& lhs, rhsT& rhs) {
    return lhs +rhs;
}
```

Would feel more "natural" since the return type is declared where it normally is, although as a result of the two arguments. Is it that this clash with something else or does it cause extra work for the compiler if the syntax was this way that's not worth it?

Comment: See also these [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11235245/3919155) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11215536/3919155).

Comment: [Why was the addition of trailing-return-types necessary in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651283/why-was-the-addition-of-trailing-return-types-necessary-in-c11)

Comment: Thank you both. Those two posts along with the link to http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html explained a lot of the "why" reasons.

Comment: In your suggestion, `lhs` is not in scope at the point you first use it

Comment: `lhs`/`rhs` are not yet declared in `decltype` in the second case.

Comment: Now try the second alternative for a lambda please.

Comment: Some of your comments seem to explain **why** something doesn't work. Although valuable, that was not the question. The question was why the syntax was decided upon. Because you COULD have made the second variant work in cases where it now doesn't. But, from what I gather, it would most likely require too much reworking of the existing compilers.

Comment: In the first example, the explicit return type `decltype(lhs + rhs)` is redundant. The compiler _can_ infer the return type.

Comment: "_the "new" C++ features_" - the features have been standardized since 2011, _i.e._, that's closer to when Angela Merkel became the first female chancellor of Germany than present day. Just saying.

Comment: @Snps That's only true in C++14 and later. The question is tagged C++11.

Comment: @aschepler You're right, had forgotten that. Anyway, while OP is reading about "new" C++ features, the limits of C++14 or even C++17 seems more interesting than the limits of a 6 year old standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Note

> Without it, the compiler would not be able to derive the return type of the template function.

This was later fixed in C++14 and the compiler doesn't need the trailing return type as it can infer the return type from the returned expression. The following works fine in C++14.

```
template <typename lhsT, typename rhsT>
auto add(const lhsT& lhs, const rhsT& rhs) {
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

---

> But why is the syntax the way it is?

The use of trailing return type is useful when the return type is deduced from the arguments, which always are declared *after* the return type (one can't refer to something that hasn't been declared yet).

Also, a trailing return type *does* appear to be more natural in the sense that functional and mathematical notation uses this kind of declaration. I think most types of notation outside of C-style declarations commonly use trailing return type. *E.g.*:

> f : X → Y

In above mathematical notation, `f` is the function name, `X` the argument, and `Y` the returned value.

Just because the flock of pink sheep reject the gray sheep doesn't make it unnatural.

In your second example it is not possible for the compiler to infer the return types as of above reason, *i.e.*, that the arguments have not yet been declared. However, inference is possible if using the template parameters and `std::declval`, *e.g.*:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>()) add(const T& lhs, const U& rhs) {
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

`std::declval` acts as a lazy instantiation of a type and never evaluates, *e.g.*, calls the constructor etc. It is mostly used when inferring types.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult for the compiler to introduce symbols prior to them being introduced.

```
template <typename lhsT, typename rhsT>
decltype(lhs + rhs) add(lhsT& lhs, rhsT& rhs) {
  return lhs +rhs;
}
```

Here, `lhs` and `rhs` are used *before* they are declared.

This is hard to get right.

```
template <typename lhsT, typename rhsT>
auto add(lhsT& lhs, rhsT& rhs) -> decltype(lhs + rhs) {
  return lhs +rhs;
}
```

here they are used after they are declared.  That is easy to get right.

C++ since C++11 has made a conscious choice to pay attention to what is hard and what it easy to implement in existing C++ compilers.  There where a number of C++98/03 features that where so hard to implement that nobody really did, and in some cases impossible (publishing templates from a .cpp file, and some of the requirements of std::string, are two of them off the top of my head).

Comment: *"It is difficult for the compiler to introduce symbols prior to them being introduced."* - A bit tautological. Did you perhaps mean "to use symbols prior..."?

Comment: @StoryTeller In one case, the actor is the programmer; in the other, the compiler.  It is difficult for the compiler to introduce symbols (into its understanding) prior to the programmer introducing them (by defining them).  And yes, it is a bit tautological; that was intentional, to make it more obvious than it would otherwise be.